# Root category and subcategories are blank

Tags: magento

After importing the products and categories, my Magento setup displays blank root category and subcategoies!

Catalog > Manage Categories displays the following page (part of screenshot):

[image]

Please note that Manage Categories page doesn't render "Add Category" input fields. Instead, it displays list of products when I click on "Add Root Category".

On the other hand, System > Manage Store > Main Store (Root Category) displays the following page (part of screenshot):

[image]

Root Category dropdown list has blank item here.

How can I solve this issue please?

Comment: Looks like your import went wrong. The titles (maybe other attributes) are missing. How did you do the import?

Comment: I used MAGMI to import products and categories. Product import is successful. After that, I updated few tables manually using SQL queries. Can SQL insertion and updating  solve it? If yes, which tables should I update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, my import operation was wrong somehow. To fix the missing attributes or categories, I tried to update the database using SQL. In Magento development environment, it is waste of time to update or import database using SQL query.

There is a nice import tool for free: MAGMI. http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/files/magmi-0.7/releases/

To import categories, MAGMI has plugins:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/files/magmi-0.7/plugins/packages/

[image]

From the above link, you can download it. After downloading the plugins, you need to upload again to your magento website. After uploading it, you need to configure as follows:

[image]

The Csv file should have categories column according to MAGMI description found on the link: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=On_the_fly_category_creator/importer

Hope that this answer is helpful to fix this similar issue.